# Turn function on and off

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a jQuery tip function. I would like to create a button to turn on and turn off the function. I want it to be on by default.

Is it possible to create  a link to turn on and off a function?

Comment: Perhaps rather than wanting to toggle the function itself, you're after a way to set a flag to determine whether to perform an action? A global variable would do it, but you could also register and de-register a bound event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically add and subtract event handlers with the [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) functions.

```
$("#id").click( function() {

    if ( HANDLER_IS_SET )
        $("#button").unbind( "click");    
    else       
        $("#button").bind( "click", myEventHandlerFunction );             
}
```

Comment: I want to use this function:  http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

Can I have a checkbox that will turn off the function?

Comment: @Erik yes you can. We won't code it for you though, but we can help if you have any questions. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can set a boolean to check if it's on or off, or bind and unbind a function.

```
var isOn = false;

$("#button").click(function(){ isOn = !isOn; });

$("#executebutton").click(MyFunction);

function MyFunction()
{
    if (!isOn) return;
    // do stuff
}
```

or

```
$("#button").click
(
    function()
    {
        if ($("#executebutton").data("events").click != undefined)
            $("#executebutton").unbind("click");
        else
            $("#executebutton").bind("click", MyFunction);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more info is needed, but you could use a global variable to toggle an if statement within the function so it doesn't execute anything, but the function will still be called.

Comment: Unhooking and rehooking is another (less ugly) alternative.